# Google Map Api comparing multiple routes

Tags: php, sql, google-maps

Am new to this Google Maps and had been scratching my head for a while.
Problem is i have a task where i need to compare two routes in google maps.
Let me give an example : person 1 is walking from position 1 to position 2. Now i have lat and long for those positions. Like this i have stored almost hundred of data in my db. Now every one have there own traveling way like some has car and some are with bicycle. Now i need to compare if any person who is driving car as same as PERSON 1 positions then fetch only those people from db.
I have tried doing this via sql query but seems this is not possible. Please help me out with this situation.

Sorry i did not mention this thing. Let me give one more scenario, Imagine Person 1 is walking from Position B to D. And other person who is Driving Car is traveling from position A to F, so B and D are on the same route hence he will give lift to Person 1. Any help is appreciated.

My Db has :- id,person name, person_start_location_lat,person_end_location_lat,person_start_location_lon,person_end_location_lon,tansist_type(car,bicycle,walk)

Comment: in your db do you define methods and the location?

Means, as you said any person driving same as person 1, then you should have say method 1 (driving) & location. So whenever the person request, if the location and method is same, then provide the solution.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check. Route might differ with different person. Its just that i wanted to find if person who is driving can give lift to the other person who is walking

Comment: seems very complicated indeed, this will take time as this is somehow like require AI to do that. However, if I'm not mistaken, google has an API that suggest routes, so it might help you ease a little. Good luck :)

Comment: :-( Thank you @MuthaFury.

Comment: related question: [How to find the overlap of polylines in order to draw the common segment as shaded on google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230611/how-to-find-the-overlap-of-polylines-in-order-to-draw-the-common-segment-as-shad)

Comment: @geocodezip :-(  Before giving minus points why don't you clarify your doubt on this question. Scenario what i have given is just an example it is more complicated then what i have described. I cannot store all the steps for the route given by google maps.
I have been provided with only starting latlng and ending latlng and now i need to match this latlng with other latlng in the database. And i need some way to match if those latlng will come to the same route. Hope you understood now. But thanks for this link it might help me some days.

Comment: Did you find any solution? if yes, can please share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us anything about your database structure, but in principle something along the lines of

```
SELECT whatever
FROM routes
WHERE route.startLat = :person1_startLat
AND route.startLng = :person1_startLng
AND route.endLat = :person1_startLat
AND route.endLng = :person1_endLng
AND travel_method = 'Car'
AND person_id != :person1_id
```

should work.

Comment: Thanx for your answer but this is not as easy. Like Person 1 is walking from Position B to D. And other person who is Driving Car is traveling from position A to F, so B and D are on the same route hence he will give lift to Person 1.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check. Route might differ with different person. Its just that i wanted to find if person who is driving can give lift to the other person who is walking

Comment: @RKD - did you get any solution ?

Comment: I know this question is a bit old, but have you found a solution to this?