# Google Map DirectionService

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to find overlap between two routes. For this I am following the accepted answer from the following link -

[How to find the overlap of polylines in order to draw the common segment as shaded on google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230611/how-to-find-the-overlap-of-polylines-in-order-to-draw-the-common-segment-as-shad)

The accepted answer suggests jsfiddle which works for me even after I remove the waypoints on the routes. Now I try the same code on a plain html on my machine. Here is the html code for this -

```
<html>

<head>

 <title>Hello World</title>

       <style>

           body, html, #map {
               width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

    <script>

        var map;

        var directionsService;

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#DD71D8",
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        var polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#0000ff",
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        var polyline3 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#ff0000",
            strokeWeight: 8
        });


        function loadRoute1() {
            var request = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244517, -97.892271),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244517, -97.892271),
                waypoints: [{
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.241532, -97.894202)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.240374, -97.891633)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890442)
                }],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    result.draggable = true;
                    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        draggable: false, // true,
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#DD71D8",
                            strokeWeight: 1
                        },
                        map: map
                    });
                    var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                    var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
                    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                        var steps = legs[i].steps;
                        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                            for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                                polyline1.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // polyline1.setMap(map);
                    if (polyline2.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                        getPolylineIntersection();
                    }
                    renderer.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }

        function loadRoute2() {
            var request = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890426),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890426),
                waypoints: [{
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.243312, -97.890877)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.242431, -97.891601)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.243145, -97.893156)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.242357, -97.893811)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.241671, -97.891783)
                }],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };


            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    result.draggable = true;
                    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        draggable: false, // true,
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#0000ff",
                            strokeWeight: 1
                        },
                        map: map
                    });
                    var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                    var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
                    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                        var steps = legs[i].steps;
                        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                            for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                                polyline2.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // polyline2.setMap(map);
                    if (polyline1.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                        getPolylineIntersection();
                    }
                    renderer.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }

        function getPolylineIntersection() {
            var commonPts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < polyline1.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < polyline2.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
                    if (polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).equals(polyline2.getPath().getAt(j))) {
                        commonPts.push({
                            lat: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).lat(),
                            lng: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).lng(),
                            route1idx: i
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            var path = [];
            var prevIdx = commonPts[0].route1idx;
            for (var i = 0; i < commonPts.length; i++) {
                if (commonPts[i].route1idx <= prevIdx + 1) {
                    path.push(commonPts[i]);
                    prevIdx = commonPts[i].route1idx;
                } else {
                    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        map: map,
                        path: path,
                        strokeWeight: 8,
                        strokeColor: "#ff0000"
                    });
                    path = [];
                    prevIdx = commonPts[i].route1idx;
                }
            }
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                map: map,
                path: path,
                strokeWeight: 8,
                strokeColor: "#ff0000"
            });

        }



        function initialize() {
            alert("Hello");
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                draggable: true,
                center: {
                    lat: 30.241532,
                    lng: -97.894202
                }
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            loadRoute1();
            loadRoute2();

        }

        initialize();

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I am getting a javascript error that says

```
Script error
js                       Line: 0
Code                     Char: 0
URI: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You're missing an API Key

Comment: So where do you put that?

Comment: After the map URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you will need to replace `yourkey` with  google api key at the bottom of the document

```
 <html>

<head>

 <title>Hello World</title>

       <style>

           body, html, #map {
               width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    </style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YourKey"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>

        var map;

        var directionsService;

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        var polyline1 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#DD71D8",
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        var polyline2 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#0000ff",
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
        var polyline3 = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path: [],
            strokeColor: "#ff0000",
            strokeWeight: 8
        });


        function loadRoute1() {
            var request = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244517, -97.892271),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244517, -97.892271),
                waypoints: [{
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.241532, -97.894202)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.240374, -97.891633)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890442)
                }],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    result.draggable = true;
                    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        draggable: false, // true,
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#DD71D8",
                            strokeWeight: 1
                        },
                        map: map
                    });
                    var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                    var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
                    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                        var steps = legs[i].steps;
                        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                            for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                                polyline1.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                     polyline1.setMap(map);
                    if (polyline2.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                        getPolylineIntersection();
                    }
                    renderer.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }

        function loadRoute2() {
            var request = {
                origin: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890426),
                destination: new google.maps.LatLng(30.244220, -97.890426),
                waypoints: [{
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.243312, -97.890877)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.242431, -97.891601)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.243145, -97.893156)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.242357, -97.893811)
                }, {
                    location: new google.maps.LatLng(30.241671, -97.891783)
                }],
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };


            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    result.draggable = true;
                    var renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                        draggable: false, // true,
                        polylineOptions: {
                            strokeColor: "#0000ff",
                            strokeWeight: 1
                        },
                        map: map
                    });
                    var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
                    var legs = result.routes[0].legs;
                    for (i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
                        var steps = legs[i].steps;
                        for (j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
                            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
                            for (k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
                                polyline2.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    polyline2.setMap(map);
                    if (polyline1.getPath().getLength() > 1) {
                        getPolylineIntersection();
                    }
                    renderer.setDirections(result);
                }
            });
        }

        function getPolylineIntersection() {
            var commonPts = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < polyline1.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < polyline2.getPath().getLength(); j++) {
                    if (polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).equals(polyline2.getPath().getAt(j))) {
                        commonPts.push({
                            lat: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).lat(),
                            lng: polyline1.getPath().getAt(i).lng(),
                            route1idx: i
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
            var path = [];
            var prevIdx = commonPts[0].route1idx;
            for (var i = 0; i < commonPts.length; i++) {
                if (commonPts[i].route1idx <= prevIdx + 1) {
                    path.push(commonPts[i]);
                    prevIdx = commonPts[i].route1idx;
                } else {
                    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                        map: map,
                        path: path,
                        strokeWeight: 8,
                        strokeColor: "#ff0000"
                    });
                    path = [];
                    prevIdx = commonPts[i].route1idx;
                }
            }
            var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
                map: map,
                path: path,
                strokeWeight: 8,
                strokeColor: "#ff0000"
            });

        }



        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                draggable: true,
                center: {
                    lat: 30.241532,
                    lng: -97.894202
                }
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

            loadRoute1();
            loadRoute2();

        }
        initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edited fixes

Comment: This loads the map but nothing else shows up. Instead I get a couple of javascript errors (A) google is not defined (line 16 i.e. where the first call is made)  and (B) polyline1 is null or not an object

Comment: updated and working, if works mark as answer please :)

Comment: Now I can see the markers but still a script error - Message: Script error
Line: 0
Char: 0
Code: 0
URI: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/28/2/poly.js

Comment: did you clear the console? and is the code exact with your API key?

Comment: nevermind...this works perfectly on chrome. IE I guess is an older version. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem, don't bother with IE